# Append-only format in DB?

Tags: couchbase

I read this sentence from couchbase document: "Both the document data and the view index information are written to storage in an append-only format. Changes to the document data and index updates create fragmentation on storage of the active data."

Can you explain append-only format in store data on disk.

Comment: Have you googled it? Seems that there are plenty of links explaining this.

Comment: Read page 6 of this document http://www.couchbase.com/sites/default/files/uploads/all/whitepapers/Couchbase_Server_Architecture_Review.pdf

Comment: Thanks for you document. I find a useful document about couchdb storage structure in couchbase. I post for someone need it.

Comment: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/couchbase-architecture-deep